# Javascript array data into form fields name=JSkey value=JSvalue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Assume I have a form which has been filled and saved to a SQL database. The form contains over 50+ input fields. The user should be able to update the form data at a later point.

So when the user clicks a certain edit button, the following happens: Data gets fetched from SQL with a PHP script and will be converted to a Javascript array.

The HTML form has input fields with 'name' attributes that are exactly the same as the keys in the Javascript array. The only thing left is to fill the HTML input value attribute with the corresponding values from the Javascript array.

I am pondering how to do this. Probably with some sort of loop or some kind of 'find and replace' function. Anyway all kind of tips or help are highly appreciated!

EDIT: A piece of example code to clarify:

```
<? php
$Formdata = ($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM FormName WHERE FormID = '$_SESSION['FormID']'");

$Formdata = json_encode($Formdata);

?>
<script>
 var FormData = jQuery.parseJSON ( '<?php echo $FormData; ?>' );
</script>"

<form>
Firstname <input type="text" name="Firstname (FIND ARRAY KEY)" value="PLACE CORRESPONDING ARRAY VALUE HERE"><br>
Address <input type="text" name="tel (FIND ARRAY KEY)" VALUE="ARRAY VALUE HERE"><br>
<input ....and so on...
</form>
```

Comment: Seeing your example code will also be highly appreciated...

Comment: Is it an array or an object? My guess is an object, but without a basic example, it is hard to tell. JavaScript 101 solution seems like the answer. A for loop with `document.formName[elementName].value = "foo";`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your php array and your form markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use **jQuery** use **jQuery("input").val()**: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kLp9vhvf/1/

Comment: I think this is what I need. I am going to try it. THANKS!